# How to Make React Router Resolve within a nested path

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I'm a little bit uncertain as to what might be wrong here.

I have a React router switch that is nested within another React Router switch as below

Switch in **homepage.js** file is as below

```
<Switch>
       <Route path={HomePageRoutes.CONTENTS}> //which is just /contents
         <ContentPage initialData={fetchedData}/>
       <Route>
       <Route path={HomePageRoutes.ADS}>
         <AdsPage/>
       </Route>
</Switch>
```

Now, ContentPage which was referenced above is in a file called **contentpage.js** and that page also contains a switch as below:

```
export default function ContentPage(){
 ......
     <Switch>
        <Route path={`/first`}>
             <FirstContentPage/>
        </Route>
        <Route>
            <DefaultContentPage/>
        </Route>
     </Switch>
 ......
}
```

I was expecting that if the current location in the browser is at say `/content` and I click on a link that redirects to `/first`, the `/first` will be appended to the current location to become `/content/first` and the `FirstContentPage` component should render but unfortunately it is not rendering?

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in anticipation for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to access the current `path` from the `match` prop. Since `ContentPage` is not receiving [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) you may need to wrap `ContentPage` in the [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) Higher Order Component.

[match](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/match)

> A match object contains information about how a `<Route path>` matched
> the URL. match objects contain the following properties:
>
> - params - (object) Key/value pairs parsed from the URL corresponding to the dynamic segments of the path
> - isExact - (boolean) true if the entire URL was matched (no trailing characters)
> - **path - (string) The path pattern used to match. Useful for building nested `<Route>`s**
> - url - (string) The matched portion of the URL. Useful for building nested `<Link>`s

```
function ContentPage({ match }) {
  const { path } = match;

  ......
    <Switch>
      <Route path={`${path}/first`}>
        <FirstContentPage/>
      </Route>
      <Route>
        <DefaultContentPage/>
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  ......
}

export default withRouter(ContentPage);
```

Comment: Oh My!!! You just saved me several hours of beating about the bush. Lolz.. Worked like a charm!!! Thank you.